# NumberFormatException - Android

Tags: android, double, numberformatexception

I've uploaded my Android app to the Market today, and I received 4 errors regarding `NumberFormatException,Double.parseDouble` and `Double.valueOf`.

Here's the Logcat I see in the Developer Console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{can.you.drive/can.you.drive.do_drive}: java.lang.NumberFormatException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1816)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1837)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException
at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDblImpl(Native Method)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:283)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:318)
at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:356)
at can.you.drive.dont_drive.roundTwoDecimals(dont_drive.java:132)
at can.you.drive.do_drive.onCreate(do_drive.java:125)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1780)
```

Here's the function in which the error occurs(according to the Log) -

```
public static double roundTwoDecimals(double d) {
    DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
}
```

I know that `d` is double.

Also, this works fine on my phone(Nexus S running 2.3.4). I'm getting the error from other users. That's why I can't really debug it.

I really don't know what my cause this on some phones.

Comment: what's in dont_drive.java, line 132?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's got to do with localization, with `.` not being the decimal separator in the platforms where the error occurs. Why don't you use a less expensive method of rounding?

```
public double round(double d, int nDecimals)
{
    for(int i=0; i<nDecimals; ++i) d *= 10d;
    d=Math.round(d);
    for(int i=0; i<nDecimals; ++i) d /= 10d;
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that method seems to work for the most part. But sometimes the output is something like 0.02899999999999998, when it should be 0.029. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: It happens because of the way floating point values are represented in memory, many of them can't be exactly represented as a `double`. I don't think you can have a workaround for that, unless you represent them through a non-floating point data structure. It all depends on what you intend to do.

Answer (score 1):

use try catch block to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the error occurs when someone from the Deutsch language uses your application. I've had this problem. They use a comma in place of a decimal (',' instead of '.'). This has thrown me off multiple times

Answer (score 0):

To debug it, add a ton of System.out.println()'s all over your code that spit out a variable when it is changed. These are easier than tools like gdb.