# Correct way to handle NumberFormatException

Tags: java, android, exception, numberformatexception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to handle number format exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683164/how-to-handle-number-format-exception)

i want to enter digit in format like $22,000,420 everything is fine but when i erase number it shows number formatting exception.

my xml file is as follows:-

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editAmountFinanced"
        style="@style/EditTextInputFinance"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtCreateNewAccount"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="AMOUNT FINANCED"
         android:digits="0123456789.,$"
        android:padding="10dp" />
```

and my android java code is as follows:-

```
 editAmountFinanced = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editAmountFinanced);

 editAmountFinanced.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        boolean isEdiging;
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,  int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isEdiging) return;
            isEdiging = true;

            String str = s.toString().replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "" );
            double s1 = Double.parseDouble(str);

            NumberFormat nf2 = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
            ((DecimalFormat)nf2).applyPattern("$ ###,###.###");
            try {

                s.replace(0, s.length(), nf2.format(s1));

                isEdiging = false;
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {

            }

        }
    });
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please search for similar questions before posting a question,
Take a look here:[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499523/how-to-avoid-number-format-exception-in-java)

in your case just put the try above double s1 =, like this

```
    double s1 = 0.0;
      try {
           s1 = Double.parseDouble(str);
     } catch(NumberFormatException e) {}
        NumberFormat nf2 = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
        ((DecimalFormat)nf2).applyPattern("$ ###,###.###");
         s.replace(0, s.length(), nf2.format(s1));

         isEdiging = false;
```

Comment: Can you explain what happens exactly ?

Comment: But with the try and catch moved around Double.parseDouble the exception should be caught... so it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: ya then m not getting any error but i want to enter $ sign and comma

Comment: Adding the above code to your catch clues will fix the problem

Comment: thamks..but that didnt help.... :(

Comment: Just edited the answer , and tested on my device , working 100%

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get answer from the folowing question and answers

[NumberFormatException - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011668/numberformatexception-android)

[lang.NumberFormatException in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206897/lang-numberformatexception-in-android)